# How to replace missing values in a numeric and categorical column using plydata package in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe in which there are missing values in various columns. I want to replace the categorical missing values in column beta by "missing" and replace the missing values in numeric columns z by the mean of the column.  I want to use plydata package in python

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 'alpha': list('a abbb'),
 'beta': list('bab uq'),
 'theta': list('cdec e'),
 'x': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6],
 'y': [6, 5, 4, 3, 2,  np.nan],
 'z': [7,  np.nan, 11, 8, 10, 12]
 })


df1 >> mutate(newcol = if_else('x==np.nan, 'missing', x'))
```

The above code is not working, hence it would be great if code is updated in line with plydata.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a series object of the output from the `pd.Series.isna()` output as your predicate, and likewise use the pandas methods to get the mean `pd.Series.mean()`. You can also use `pd.Series.isin()` to check multiple criteria (NaN, empty strings, or a space, etc.). To replace with a string and not a value, you need to quote the word as a string within the python string (`'"missing"'`)

In other words

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "alpha": list("a abbb"),
        "beta": list("bab uq"),
        "theta": list("cdec e"),
        "x": [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6],
        "y": [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, np.nan],
        "z": [7, np.nan, 11, 8, 10, 12],
    }
)

df = df >> define(new_z=if_else(df.z.isna(), df.z.mean(), 'z')) 
df = df >> define(newcol = if_else(df.beta.isin([np.nan, " "]), '"missing"', 'beta'))
```

Upon looking through the docs it looks like its best to use the `define` method here instead of the `mutate` method since mutate is an alias towards define anyway (see [here](https://plydata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plydata.one_table_verbs.mutate.html#plydata.one_table_verbs.mutate)).